# Extract name entities from web domain address

Tags: python, string, machine-learning, nlp

I am working on an NLP problem (in Python 2.7) to extract the location of a news report from the text inside the report. For this task I am using the Clavin API which works well enough.

However I've noticed that the name of the location area is often mentioned in the URL of the report itself and I'd like to find a way to extract this entity from a domain name, to increase the level of accuracy from Clavin by providing an additional named entity in the request.

In an ideal world I'd like to be able to give this input:

`www.britainnews.net`

and return this, or a similar, output:

`[www,britain,news,net]`

Of course I can use .split() feature to separate the `www` and `net` tokens which are unimportant, however I'm stumped as to how to split the middle phrase without an intensive dictionary lookup.

I'm not asking for someone to solve this problem or write any code for me - but this is an open call for suggestions as to the ideal NLP library (if one exists) or any ideas as to how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check - [Word Segmentation Task](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/How%20to%20Do%20Things%20with%20Words.ipynb) from [Norvig](http://norvig.com/)'s work.

```
from __future__ import division
from collections import Counter
import re, nltk

WORDS = nltk.corpus.reuters.words()

COUNTS = Counter(WORDS)

def pdist(counter):
    "Make a probability distribution, given evidence from a Counter."
    N = sum(counter.values())
    return lambda x: counter[x]/N

P = pdist(COUNTS)

def Pwords(words):
    "Probability of words, assuming each word is independent of others."
    return product(P(w) for w in words)

def product(nums):
    "Multiply the numbers together.  (Like `sum`, but with multiplication.)"
    result = 1
    for x in nums:
        result *= x
    return result

def splits(text, start=0, L=20):
    "Return a list of all (first, rest) pairs; start <= len(first) <= L."
    return [(text[:i], text[i:]) 
            for i in range(start, min(len(text), L)+1)]

def segment(text):
    "Return a list of words that is the most probable segmentation of text."
    if not text: 
        return []
    else:
        candidates = ([first] + segment(rest) 
                      for (first, rest) in splits(text, 1))
        return max(candidates, key=Pwords)

print segment('britainnews')     # ['britain', 'news']
```

More examples at : [Word Segmentation Task](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/How%20to%20Do%20Things%20with%20Words.ipynb)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Comment: Click on accept, if this answer solved your problem [ click on correct mark ], As it will be useful for others as well.